# Magnetic flux decimal value meaning

Tags: magnetic-fields

Why can magnetic flux have non-integer values despite that it represents the number of magnetic field lines that cross a surface perpendicularly, which means it should be integers only? What sense does that (being decimal sometimes) have?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the sentence

> "it represents the number of magnetic field lines that cross a surface perpendicularly"

That is a common way to illustrate what the flux is, but it's dangerous because it can lead to confusions like this one.

First, let's make clear what field lines are. You know that, when there is a magnet, a field appears. The magnetic field is a field, that means that "for **all points** in space, tehre is now a vector $\vec{B}$". Every single point in space has a vector $\vec{B}$.

If you join those arrows in curves (tangentially), you get field lines.

But check that there are vectors filling every single point in space. That's infinite and infinitesimal. If you zoom in forever, you'll keep seeing it all full of vectors.

So there are infinite vectors, and hence infinite field lines. Infinite field lines, so, no matter how small you pick a surface, there will always be infinite lines crossing that surface.

As you can see, the definition you gave "fails" here. That's because you must understand it well:

As there are infinite possible lines, we do not represent them all, obviously. We choose how many lines we want to draw. They must be more than 2 for each source, and the number of lines we pick must be proportional to the strength of the source.

So we only represent a few. But that few is proportional to the strength of the source. That's why you can have a "fractional number" of line. That's just an invention, because it is an indicator of the strength of the magnetic field along the surface.

---

I hope that cleared your doubt. Nevertheless, I keep disliking that way of thinking. Instead, I like to recall the original meaning of flux. Have you ever wondered why it has that name? It is related to fluid mechanics.

In fluid mechanics, the flow rate $\mathcal{Q}$ is calculated in the same way: integrating the product $\vec{v}\cdot d\vec{S}$. That is computing the velocity along a perpendicular surface.

The reason is that we want to calculate the amount of water (volume) that flows through time ($m^3/s$).

$$\mathcal{Q}= \frac{\Delta V}{\Delta t}=\frac{ A\cdot \Delta x}{\Delta t} = \frac{ A \cdot v \Delta t}{\Delta t} = A\cdot v $$

Where $A$ is the transverse area, of course.

So the flow rate measures how much water gets accumulated per unit time, and it dos that by calculating how fast water passes through a surface.

Well, velocity can be regarded as a field as well. There is a velocity field along the whole fluid.

This concept was extended to electric and magnetic fields, but now, instead of $v$, we write $B$. But the concept remains the same: how intense are the field arrows that are crossing a surface.

Of course this concept is useful when it appears in formulas, so we can be interested in calculating it; whereas in fluid mechanics it's been usefuil from the very beginning.

Comment: So it doesn't really equal to the number of lines? Rather it's a scale of magnetic field's intensity over a surface?

Comment: In fact, that is the definition: $B\cdot dS\cdot \cos(\alpha)$. If you want to interpret it as number of field lines crossing the surface, you must interpret that you draw as many lines as you want, in order to represent the intensity. And if you draw 5 lines for 1T and 10 lines for 2T, it is very possible that you find a fractional number. Again, that's why I prefer the flow rate interpretation.